# fixcmex does not fix

Tags: fonts, computer-modern, lmodern

The [`fixcmex`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/fixcmex) package is supposed to restore the `cmex` font and make it scaleable using several sizes provided by `amsmath`, even if the `lmodern` package has been loaded which overrides it with the `lmex` font which has just a single design size.

As can be seen below, this does not work for me. The extension font is still set to `lmex10`, the `\widetilde` does not scale at all, and the `\big` delimiters are larger than they should be.

The strange thing is as follows: The core of the package is the  `\fixcmex@fix` command, which should be executed automatically via `\AtBeginDocument`. I can tell that it is definitely being executed, but somehow it doesn't manage to replace the font. But if I just issue that command directly during the preamble, then the font is replaced.

So, why doesn't it work automatically as it should?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{fixcmex}
% \makeatletter\fixcmex@fix\makeatother% is we uncomment this, then scaleable cmex is used
\begin{document}
$\widetilde{x}^{\widetilde{x}^{\widetilde{x}}}$
$\Biggl[\biggl[\Bigl[\bigl[[)\bigr)\Bigr)\biggr)\Biggr)$
\fontname\textfont3
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.16
 *File List*
standalone.cls    2015/07/15 v1.2 Class to compile TeX sub-files standalone
ifluatex.sty    2010/03/01 v1.3 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
   ifpdf.sty    2011/01/30 v2.3 Provides the ifpdf switch (HO)
 ifxetex.sty    2010/09/12 v0.6 Provides ifxetex conditional
 xkeyval.sty    2014/12/03 v2.7a package option processing (HA)
 xkeyval.tex    2014/12/03 v2.7a key=value parser (HA)
standalone.cfg    2015/07/15 v1.2 Default configuration file for 'standalone' c
lass
 article.cls    2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
  size12.clo    2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
 lmodern.sty    2009/10/30 v1.6 Latin Modern Fonts
 fontenc.sty
   t1enc.def    2005/09/27 v1.99g Standard LaTeX file
 amsmath.sty    2013/01/14 v2.14 AMS math features
 amstext.sty    2000/06/29 v2.01
  amsgen.sty    1999/11/30 v2.0
  amsbsy.sty    1999/11/29 v1.2d
  amsopn.sty    1999/12/14 v2.01 operator names
 fixcmex.sty    2015/11/10 v1.0 Scalable math extensions font (Enrico Gregorio)

   t1lmr.fd    2009/10/30 v1.6 Font defs for Latin Modern
  ot1lmr.fd    2009/10/30 v1.6 Font defs for Latin Modern
  omllmm.fd    2009/10/30 v1.6 Font defs for Latin Modern
 omslmsy.fd    2009/10/30 v1.6 Font defs for Latin Modern
 omxlmex.fd    2009/10/30 v1.6 Font defs for Latin Modern
 ***********
```

Comment: A new version fixing the issue has been uploaded to CTAN.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a bug report